# Facebook Clicks not matching Google Analytics Sessions

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, measurement

I recently set up a Facebook ad campaign to drive website clicks to the home page of my site.

In Facebook I used the Campaign Objective: "website clicks" when creating the campaign, set my various targeting options and optimised for "Link clicks to your website"

I ran 5 ads in the set, each one with a custom landing URL so that I could check behaviour data in Analytics per ad: eg Ad1 directed to www.example.com/home?src=ad1, etc.

The problem I am facing is that Facebook is telling me that my ads have had x number of clicks, but in Google Analytics, when I check the landing pages report and segment out the URL's containing "src=ad" I'm getting a very different value in the sessions column. Facebook is reporting almost double the number of website clicks as what I am getting in the GA landing page sessions report.

I was expecting a slight difference, however, what could be the cause of such a significant difference in values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not too uncommon to see such a discrepancy in Facebook ad clicks vs Google Analytics sessions. A couple reasons for this:

1. Users can bounce before triggering a page load, particularly for slower-loading pages. I've found this is the most common issue.
2. Users could click once on an ad, and click again within 30 minutes, registering as only 1 session in Google Analytics (navigating back to Facebook and re-clicking due to slow load, for example).
3. A filter in Google Analytics may be weeding out some sessions.

Check out [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57906/less-than-half-of-facebook-ad-clicks-are-visible-in-google-analytics) answer.